# Unable to start the program, System cannot find the file specified VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The problem is that when I try to debug is gives me the error message in this topic title.
I have checked the debug command and it is pointing to the correct location of the General Output Directory and the Linker Output File.

I've had this problem before and the above solution would fix it, but this time I'm stumped.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I just learned about the configuration settings and macros in VS a couple hours ago so it wouldn't be surprising if the error would be a simple one I didn't notice.

Comment: Make sure you are building and running the same configuration. Also make sure Linker > General > Output file specifies the right path and file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the file it cannot find isn't the executable itself, but a dependency of it, such as a DLL.

Make sure that:

1. You have *really* rebuilt the project
2. You have specified the correct executable
3. The "Current working directory" is someplace from which you can see the Dependant DLLs

Comment: Turns out my linking was not correct and it wasn't actually rebuilding, got it working now though, thanks for the help!